# Simple Effects in Angular 2+ application using Firebase, NGRX and RXJS

Tags: javascript, angular-2+

Made an Angular app using Firebase, RXJS and NGRX.

```
@Effect()
createQuiz$: Observable<Action> = this.actions$.pipe(
    ofType<quizAction.CreateQuiz>(quizAction.CREATE_QUIZ),
    switchMap((action) => {
        return this.quizService.createQuiz(action.payload)
        .pipe(
        map(() => {
            return new quizAction.CreateQuizCompleted()
        }),
        catchError(error => {
            console.log(error);
            return of(new quizAction.CreateQuizCompleted());
        })
        );
    })
);




@Effect()
updateQuiz$: Observable<Action> = this.actions$.pipe(
    ofType<quizAction.UpdateQuiz>(quizAction.UPDATE_QUIZ),
    switchMap((action) => {
        return this.quizService.updateQuiz(action.payload)
        .pipe(
        map(() => {
            return new quizAction.UpdateQuizCompleted()
        }),
        catchError(error => {
            console.log(error);
            return of(new quizAction.UpdateQuizCompleted());
        })
        );
    })
);



@Effect()
deleteQuiz$: Observable<Action> = this.actions$.pipe(
    ofType<quizAction.DeleteQuiz>(quizAction.DELETE_QUIZ),
    switchMap((action) => {
        return this.quizService.deleteQuiz(action.payload)
        .pipe(
        map(() => {
            return new quizAction.DeleteQuizCompleted()
        }),
        catchError(error => {
            console.log(error);
            return of(new quizAction.DeleteQuizCompleted());
        })
        );
    })
);
```

These are the NGRX effects. They are triggering a reducer function, then call a service function and then trigger another reducer function upon completion.

```
export class QuizComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(
    private quizService: QuizService, 
    private store:Store<{app: fromApp.State}>,
  ) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
  }

  trackByIdx = (index: number): number => index;

  onCreate(): void {
    this.store.select(fromApp.selectUserId).pipe(
      take(1)
    ).subscribe(userId => this.handleCreate(userId));
  }
  
  onDelete(id: string): void {
    this.store.dispatch(new AppAction.DeletePoll(id));
  }
  
  onEdit(): void {
    let value = this.quizService.createCustomQuiz();
    if (this.quizService.hasPermission(userId) && this.pollService.validateQuiz(value)) {
      this.store.dispatch(new quizAction.UpdatePoll(value));
    }
  }

  handleCreate(userId: string): void {
    let value = this.quizService.createDefaultQuiz();
    if (this.quizService.hasPermission(userId) && this.quizService.validateQuiz(value)) {
      this.store.dispatch(new quizAction.CreateQuiz(value));
    }
  }
}
```

This is the component that dispatches the actions.

```
  createQuiz(quiz:Quiz) {
    const id = this.db.createId();
    return from(
      this.db
        .collection('quizzes')
        .doc(id)
        .set({...quiz, id: id})
    );
    
  }

  updateQuiz(quiz:Quiz) {
    return from(
      this.db
        .collection('quizzes')
        .doc(quiz.id)
        .set(quiz, { merge: false })
    );
  }

  deleteQuiz(id:string) {
    return from(
      this.db
        .collection('quizzes')
        .doc(id)
        .delete()
    );
  }
```

These are the service methods. I am wondering if there's any improvement and if switchmap and map are correctly used.